# Online payment with magento

Tags: payment, payment-methods

I wanna integrate a payment online service in my magento website.

I activate saved CC in payment methods and I get a form to put some informations (like card number and expiration date).

Like this:
[image]

But my problem is that I want to make this form open in a secure page and not in that same page (prepared in advance by the bank in charge of payment actions).

How can I change that ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a third party extension (e.g. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/the-official-ingenico-former-ogone-extension.html) which handles the online payment for you. You should not use the saved credit card payment method since it's not PCI compliant because it saves the credit card data in your store. Furthmore you can not do online capturing/refunding by using this payment method. 
In order to secure your checkout process you need to set up https properly and set the 'Use Secure URLs in Frontend' setting to yes.